# Gruntfile.js SASS Task Configuration

Tags: css, ruby, node.js, sass, gruntjs

Line `'css/???????': 'sass/???????'` of the following is what I can not sort out.  I have sass-globbing installed due to having multiple directories and levels of SASS files.  There are 4 independently compiled sass files in my /sass directory.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['sass/{,**/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass:dist']
            },
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false,
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/???????': 'sass/???????'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dist', 'watch']);
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

Comment: This would depend entirely on your directory structure, what the files are named, and whether or not you include other files. Can you post that information?

Answer (score 0):

This should be working;

```
dist: {
     files: {
                    'css/style.css': 'sass/**/*.scss'
                }
            }
```